# Get name of a process that uses above certain amount of CPU

Tags: powershell, process, cpu

I've been googling around trying to figure out if there's a clever way to get the name of a process that uses above an X% CPU. For example, in our environment, there are certain processes that end up hogging the CPU, and in most cases it's so bad we're not able to connect to the server to see which one it is.

**Basically this is how I imagine it working:**
If a function that finds a process with more than 70% CPU usage then an SMS will be sent out to the necessary recipients which includes server name and the process name.

The SMS part I have figured out, however, the CPUUsage is troublesome. The if-statement always seem to end up with writing "There are no processes above 1% CPU usage" even if there are some. In addition, how would I go about getting the process name into the function that sends out SMS?

```
    function CPUUsage ()
{
    $process = get-process
    foreach ($pro in $process){
    $name = $pro.ProcessName
    $CpuCores = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Processor).NumberOfCores
    $CpuValue = ((Get-Counter "\Process($name)\% Processor Time").CounterSamples.CookedValue)/$CpuCores
    $percent = [Decimal]::Round($CpuValue, 3)
    if($percent -gt 1)
        {
            Write-Host $name
        } else {
            Write-Host "There are no processes above 1% CPU usage"   
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CPU Usage function looks proper. I would suggest to add write-host on each process name along with percentage.

```
Write-Host $name has $CpuValue % of CPU Usage.
```

for testing purpose, you can put Where-Object on heavy application (like Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "Skype"} ). In such case it should go within if condition.

```
$process = get-process | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "Skype"} 
    foreach ($pro in $process){
    $name = $pro.ProcessName
    $CpuCores = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Processor).NumberOfCores
    $CpuValue = ((Get-Counter "\Process($name)\% Processor Time").CounterSamples.CookedValue)/$CpuCores

    $percent = [Decimal]::Round($CpuValue, 3)

    Write-Host $name has $percent % of CPU Usage.

    if($percent -gt 1)
    {
        Write-Host $name
    } 
}
```

Output should be like

```
Skype has 46.655 % of CPU Usage.
Skype
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to get me close to my goal. How would I go about the SMS forwarding. I've tried this:
If (CPUUsage($percent) -gt 3)
{ 
    SMS
}

but I'm not receiving a text message, even though it writes the following to host:
Idle has 119,183 % of CPU Usage.

(I purposely put only the "Idle")